# lint-staged in Angular monorepo

Tags: angular, lint-staged

I'm trying to set up `lint-staged` with my Angular monorepo workspace, however I can't make it work.
When `ng lint --files` is executed with changed file it errors that `*file* is not part of a TypeScript project`. 
If I run `ng lint <project> --files` it works. Can Angular lint all projects using files from `lint-staged`?

I need to run linting of only changed parts, but I don't see how I can achieve this.

I've no default project in `angular.json`, however `ng lint` appears to start from the first project and if it doesn't find the file it errors.

Answer (score 1):

There are some command line arguments problem with `ng lint`. You need to use this shim: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-lint-staged